# Hbase shell - Find all rows where a column does not exist

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I have setup Hbase 0.98 with huge data. Being noSQL database, HBase allows each row to have different set of columns in a column family. To filter a specific column, I can use this command

```
scan 'tb_webpage',{COLUMNS => 't:ad'}
```

What if I have to invert the condition, i.e. get all rows where "ad" does NOT exist as a column in a column family?

Answer (score 1):

Use `QualifierFilter`,

```
scan 'tb_webpage',{FILTER => "QualifierFilter(!=, 'binary:ad')"}
```

Comment: this works for one column(cd) for me, but not for another(rcd), do you know why?